# How can you hold a TCP connection open for multiple send/receive requests?

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, tcpclient

I have a Windows Service that handles different client requests from clients we have out in the field.  It works fine, I have code similar to this on the Server:

```
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ae.End(), null);   
    yield return 1;                                

    // socket connection has been established.
    TcpClient client;
    try {
        client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(ae.DequeueAsyncResult());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.Error(e.ToString());
        yield break;
    }

    using (client) {

        // Set up another listener.
        Start(server);

        using (Stream stream = client.GetStream()) {   

        ... All the work happens here and stream is returned to the client

        }
    }
```

This works fine when a client sends a request for say, request1, and gets a reply1, but if the client immediately sends a request2 immediately following this, it needs to connect again and then receive a reply2.  Sometimes this connection can take up to 3 seconds (when using a 3G client).

I would like to have it where the Server listens and if a connection is established, can receive/respond via the stream for multiple requests, then after a "end" request is sent from the client, will drop the connection.  I would imagine this would be much faster, is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When the `using` block exits, the `client` variable will be disposed causing the connection to be closed.  Get rid of the `using` block...

Comment: thanks @Idle_Mind, but I tried that already, but how do I get the stream on the next request?

Comment: ...you just either call the synchronous receive method in a loop, or if you're using the async receive you have to call it again.  Each call only results in one "receive" so you have to keep calling it to get the next packet after you've processed the current one.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I tried it, but when it looped around it bombed on the Stream stream = client.GetStream() call the second time around.  Any chance you could provide a quick code sample?

Comment: The client itself is often stored (a class instance usually) in the "state" parameter when you call BeginReceive().  That way it can be cast back and retrieved in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work!  Now I have one last concern, can I have some sort of "timeout" in case the client doesn't send the end packet, I would then have an open connection that could be held forever.

Comment: @MarkKadlec - Are you tied to creating your own solution? Were you aware of existing solutions such as http://www.networkcomms.net? Disclaimer: I'm a developer for this.

Comment: Thanks @MarcF, I'll check it out.  Hehe, +1 for the disclaimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, @Idle_Mind definitely had the right suggestion, the using{} block was causing the connection to be held.  The problem when I first removed the using was that the client was accidentally closing the connection after the first loop.

I remedied the issue on the client end and now just loop and hang on a wait, was still wondering if there was a way to time out eventually (if the client does nothing for say 1 minute), but I'm okay with having the client end the connection.